# Fill a string[] array using split

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the following text
`part1:part2`

and the following string[] array
`string[] tmp = new string[3];`

how can i split my text and put it into the array so the array looks like this:
`{"part1", "part2", ""}`

I tried using the `.split(':');` but that just reassigns the array and so it has only **2** elements instead of **3**

thanks

Comment: You only have two elements, how do you expect three elements from the split ?

Comment: string[] tmp = new string[3]; no need to specify how many elements in tmp

Comment: So you always want to add an empty string to the end of the array, regardless of what the input context contains?

Comment: Do it manually as there is not 3rd element...

Comment: ...i know there are only 2 elements hence it wont work. that is why im asking for an alternative. no need to mark down if you don't understand the question!!

Comment: @KendeJong I know i have to do it manually but i didn't know how so i asked this question and levi's answer explained it well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I am **sure** that there is a better way to do what you are trying to do, in my opinion the easiest way to achieve **precisely** the result you are after is to do a copy:

```
var input = "text1:text2";
var temp = new [] {"", "", ""};
var split = input.Split(':');
Array.Copy(split, temp, split.Length <= 3 ? split.Length : 3);
```

Comment: +1 although this answer doesn't result in *precisely* what the OP requested. The last element is `null` instead of `""`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Ah missed that! Fixed the response ;)

Comment: Is that *really* the only way to achieve that result? Seems unlikely.

Answer (score 4):

not overly elegant, but if it's what you want, you can [Resize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) the array.

```
string input=@"part1:part2";
var result = input.Split(':');

Array.Resize(ref result, 3);
result[2]=string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need three elements in the resulting array, you will have to copy the result from `string.Split` to the final array, e.g. by using a simple loop:

```
var result = new string[3];
var split = "part1:part2".Split(":");

for(var i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i)
{
    if(i < split.Length)
        result[i] = split[i];
    else
        result[i] = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "part1:part2";
var result = new string[3];
result = (str + "".PadLeft(result.Length - str.Count(c=>c==':') - 1,':')).Split(':');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static string[]  ProcessInput(string input, int length)
    {
        // handle empty or null input
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return null;

        var items = input.Split(':').ToList();
        // adding empty strings untill given length
        while (items.Count <= length)
        {
            items.Add(string.Empty);
        }
        //even split return more items than length return expected length
        return items.Take(length).ToArray();
    }
```

call the method as

```
var result =  ProcessInput("text1:text2:text4:text5", 3);
```